# React / Typescript Issue - Props not able to pass from inherited class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My interface (this is extending the react-responsive-carousel library's props interface

```ts
import {CarouselProps} from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import SCarouselCard from './SCarouselCard';

interface SCarouselProps extends CarouselProps
{
  style: Record<string, any>
  cards: Array<SCarouselCard>
  id: string
  interval: number
  infiniteLoop: boolean
}

export default SCarouselProps;
```

My "card" class (this is only partially relevant

```tsx
class SCarouselCard {
    private elements: Array<JSX.Element>;
  
    constructor(els?: Array<JSX.Element>) {
      this.elements = els ? els : [];
    }
    addElement(el: JSX.Element) {
      this.elements.push(el);
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.elements.map((e, i) => (
            <div key={i}>{e}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default SCarouselCard;
```

My actual carousel component, which is relevant to the issue I'm trying to resolve...

```tsx
import SCarouselProps from './SCarouselProps';
import SCarouselCard from './SCarouselCard'
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';

class SCarousel extends Carousel
{
    id: string = "";
    style: Record<string, any> = {};
    interval: number = 100000;
    cards: Array<SCarouselCard> = [];
    constructor(props: SCarouselProps) {

        super(props);
        this.id = props.id
        this.style = props.style
        this.interval = props.interval;
        

        this.autoPlay();
      }
      private pause() {
        //this.setState({ autoPlay: false });
        this.destroyAutoPlay();
      }
      private resume() {
        //this.setState({ autoPlay: true });
        this.clearAutoPlay();
        this.autoPlay();
      }
      componentDidUpdate() {
        const videos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll<HTMLVideoElement>(`#${this.id} video`));
        videos.forEach((video) => {
          video.onplay = () => {
            this.pause();
          };
          video.onpause = () => {
            this.resume();
          };
        });
      }
      render() {
            return <div style={this.style} id={this.id}>
            <Carousel autoPlay={true} interval={this.interval} infiniteLoop={true} showThumbs={false}>
            {this.cards.map((card, i) => (
                <div key={`s_card_${i}`}>{card.render()}</div>
            ))}
            </Carousel>
        </div>

      }
}

export default SCarousel;
```

The issue I'm facing is that when do this...

```tsx
<SCarousel id={'my_id_here'} style={{}}, etc./> ...
```

Error message:
Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Pick<Readonly, never> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Pick<Readonly, never> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'

it won't let me pass style, cards, id, interval, infiniteLoop, etc that are properties in my interface that extends from CarouselProps. Typescript is complaining about any props I try to pass, other than the original properties that are inherited from the base interface. Please help?

Comment: There shouldn't be any commas between your props in JSX

Comment: thanks. I don't have commas in my code there, it was just for illustrative purposes. Sorry about the confusion, but there's still an issue

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the error message(s) in full?

Comment: @Phil

OK, just included the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stating that the component implements the `Component` interface with those props

```
class SCarousel extends Carousel implements React.Component<SCarouselProps> {
...
}
```

Since you're extending `Carousel` it assumes it has the same interface, I don't believe typescript infers the type based on constructor parameters.

Note: additional properties will need to be optional for this to work

---

In React's docs they actually tell you to avoid inheritance, and that they have never found a case where they recommend it: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

In this case you can see that inheritance doesn't make sense, because you are returning an instance of `Carousel` in the render function. So making this component an instance of `Carousel` as well would actually create two separate Carousels in memory. Calling the `Carousel` methods from `SCarousel` (using `this.method()`) would not actually affect the component you instantianted in `render` - they are two separate components.

So, simply extend `React.Component`, and pass the props down through. Design your new component accordingly.

```
class SCarousel extends React.Component<SCarouselProps> {
...
  render(){
    return (
      ...
      <Carousel {...this.props} >
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Class 'SCarousel' incorrectly implements class 'Component<SCarouselProps, {}, any>'. Did you mean to extend 'Component<SCarouselProps, {}, any>' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'Readonly<CarouselProps>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<SCarouselProps>'.
      Type 'Readonly<CarouselProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<SCarouselProps>': style, cards, id

I have tried assigning all values required in the interface in my JSX, but it always complains about the first property I specify in the JSX

Comment: Hmm, yeah, well it does work if you make all the additional properties optional, but I will see if there is maybe a better way.

Comment: @ThomasLernberger Question though: does it really make sense to extend the `Carousel` component class, when you are returning an instance of `Carousel`? Wouldn't it make more sense to just extend `React.Component<SCarouselProps>` and use the Carousel as normal, passing the props through? Do you really need to call methods directly from the class? I think the reason why this is difficult may be because it is an anti-pattern.